# What is difference between 'call' and '__call__' in TensorFlow BasicLSTMCell implementation?

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am studying Tensorflow [BasicLSTMCell](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/BasicLSTMCell#class_basiclstmcell) while I found that there are two similar methods within the class: `__call__` and `call`. The two methods has the same parameters and the documentation does not say the difference. Refering the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/c5f94b10bbb30e525fa3ca313e7ccb173040c90a/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell.py#L256) does not give me any clue of this. But I am guessing that the the `__call__` method is inherited from somewhere, and `call` overrides `__call__`. If this is the case, why not just use `__call__` instead of `call` in the source code?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into similar problem when studying **RNNCell**.

It is in Class **Layer** in **base_layer.py** that **__call__** wraps in **call**, "applying pre- and post-processing steps".

Answer (score 1):

The method  `__call__()` does not builds the model. It just carries out the forward pass in the model. When you use `call()`, it builds the model. You can see the difference when you call `model.summary()`. The first method will give ValueError while the later will work fine.

There is another method called `build()`. The best practice is to declare the `tf.Variables()` inside this method (when you get to know the input shape) instead of `__init__()` method. This method later builds the model.

Conclusion: If you use `call()` it will work same as `__call__` and additionally, it will also build the model. But if you really want to use the later then, also declare `build()` along with it.